# How does Skype technically process video streams on older Android devices?

Tags: android, video, android-camera

Whereas on Android 4.2 and up camera2 allows me to grab the raw data stream from the camera, older devices only allow me to write the encoded stream to a file.

I ran Skype on some older devices (e.g. SDK 10) and was able to make a video call, which means that Skype must somehow be able to grab the unencoded stream before it is encoded and written to file.

I found some interesting articles on the web,

- http://www.hnwatcher.com/r/1170899/Video-recording-and-processing-in-Android/
- http://code.google.com/p/ipcamera-for-android/
- https://github.com/NanoHttpd/nanohttpd/

but I don't see how this would be working reliably and across all devices.

I was able to read out the encoded file while Android was still writing the video, but the problem here was that Android writes the MOOV box to the end of the file and only when recording has stopped. So the information in the MDAT box is worthless before the file is closed.

Does anybody know of a library that I could use to grab the data stream from the camera and immediately use it as live stream? Has anybody tried to find out how Skype does this technically?

Comment: If I had to guess, they are just using camera preview frames. Vine creates their videos that way.

Comment: That is very interesting. Do you know from which source these frames are being taken? Do they write into the surface/texture view and take it from there or is there a more direct way?

Comment: "Do you know from which source these frames are being taken?" -- `android.hardware.Camera` has a preview callback API. The mechanism is probably different for `android.hardware.camera2` (Android 5.0+), as lots of things are different for that...

Comment: http://code.google.com/p/spydroid-ipcamera, they make local streaming and remux file with sending